# Cant start Spinnaker UI Deck

Tags: spinnaker

Getting error in spinnaker when we start the web-ui.
Get stuck too much. The error i got is:

```
vendor.bundle.js:9331 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module netflix.spinnaker due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module spinnaker.core due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module spinnaker.core.notification.types due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined at Object.register
```

thanks .

Comment: please confirm if you resolve this and mention what type of spinnaker set up were you testing!

Answer (score 1):

1. What spinnaker version do you run?
2. Upgrade spinnaker first
3. perhaps use [Minnaker OSS](https://github.com/armory/minnaker) to get started faster for PoC.